# Calling a Object Oriented function from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, validation, form-submit

I am kind of new to JQuery and Javascript and need your help on what I am missing here.  I know the code works in jsfiddle.net but when I actually run it on my computer it's not doing anything. I want to keep the Object Oriented functions in "updated-formcheck.js" file separately.

I have a form validation HTML file with a jQuery function that calls my "updated-formcheck.js" file that checks all the empty fields and returns a msg.  But when a submit button is clicked, nothing happens.  Can you tell me why?

HTML file:

```
<script src="updated-formcheck.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 

<form id="myform" method="post" action="#">
<fieldset>
    <label for="attendee">I am a...<font color="red">*</font>:<br />
    <br />
  </label>
    <select id="attendee" name="attendee" >
        <option value="">-- Please Choose --</option>
        <option value="RETURNING" >Returning Attendee</option>
        <option value="FIRST_TIME" >First Time Attendee</option>
    </select>

    <label for="fullName"><br />
    <br />
  Full Name<font color="red">*</font>:</label>
    <p><input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" value="" />
    </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
<label for="address1">Street Address<font color="red">*</font>:</label>
    <p>
      <input type="text" id="address1" name="address1" value=""/>
 </p>
    <p>     
      <input type="text" id="address2" name="address2" value="" />

    </p>
    <label for="city"><br />
  City<font color="red">*</font>:</label>

    <p>
      <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="" />

    </p>
    <label for="stateProvince"><br />
  State/County/Province:</label>
    <p>
      <input type="text" id="stateProvince" name="stateProvince" value="" />
    </p>      
<label for="zipPostalCode">ZIP/Postal Code:<br />
</label>
    <p>
      <input type="text" id="zipPostalCode" name="zipPostalCode" value="" />
    </p>


    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
</fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {
        validateNow(e);
    });
});

</script>
```

In "updated-formcheck.js" file:

```
function validateNow(eventObj){
    var isValid = true; 
    $('input[type="text"].required, textarea.required, select.required').each(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
            isValid = false;
            $(this).css({
                "border": "1px solid red",
                "background": "#FFCECE"
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({
                "border": "",
                "background": ""
            });
        }
    });
    if (isValid == false) {
        eventObj.preventDefault();
        alert(this.e);
    }else 
        this.s;
}
```

Comment: Is there an error on the JavaScript console?

Comment: Glancing over your code, it looks like it should work. What have you done so far to find out what the source of the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because

```
$('input[type="text"].required, textarea.required, select.required')
```

in your code currently return an empty array, so each function is not called.

This is because you are looking for dom elements with a css class "required" that you doesn't have.

Comment: you're right! I was working on the HTML doc that didn't have class=required.  thanks for the input!!!!

Answer (score 0):

To get your code working I added a "required" class, which your js code is looking for, on the city element. I also updated the jQuery bind event to the form submit instead of a button click.

```
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="myform" method="post" action="#">
  <fieldset>
      <label for="attendee">I am a...<font color="red">*</font>:<br />
      <br />
    </label>
      <select id="attendee" name="attendee" >
          <option value="">-- Please Choose --</option>
          <option value="RETURNING" >Returning Attendee</option>
          <option value="FIRST_TIME" >First Time Attendee</option>
      </select>
      <label for="fullName"><br />
      <br />
    Full Name<font color="red">*</font>:</label>
      <p><input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" value="" />
      </p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <label for="address1">Street Address<font color="red">*</font>:</label>
      <p>
        <input type="text" id="address1" name="address1" value=""/>
   </p>
      <p>     
        <input type="text" id="address2" name="address2" value="" />
      </p>
      <label for="city"><br />
    City<font color="red">*</font>:</label>
      <p>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="" class="required" />
      </p>
      <label for="stateProvince"><br />
    State/County/Province:</label>
      <p>
        <input type="text" id="stateProvince" name="stateProvince" value="" />
      </p>      
  <label for="zipPostalCode">ZIP/Postal Code:<br />
  </label>
      <p>
        <input type="text" id="zipPostalCode" name="zipPostalCode" value="" />
      </p>
      <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="updated-formcheck.js" ></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
          //e.preventDefault();
          validateNow(e);
          return false;
      });
  });
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Yes, you're right! I was missing class="required" field.  Thanks for your input!!